# A set theory problem from Bruckner Analysis

Tags: measure-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Following is from Bruckner's book *Analysis* (Theorem 5.29 (Radon–Nikodym)) :

> Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let
> $$f_n(x)=\max_{i\leq n}g_i(x).$$
> For $M\in\mathcal{M}$, $M\subset E$, let $B_0=\varnothing$ and, for $i\leqslant n$, inductively define
> $$B_i=\bigl(\{x:f_n(x)=g_i(x)\}\cap M\bigr)\setminus B_{i-1}.$$
> Then $\color{blue}{M=\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i.}\ \color{red}{\text{This is a disjoint union.}}$ Thus
> $$\int_Mf_n\,d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{B_i}g_i\,d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{B_i\cap E_i^k}g_i\,d\mu.\tag{16}$$

I long thought for both the claims (highlighted in blue and red) and I couldn't prove them. Specially the sets being disjoint seems to be wrong by van diagram.  Please help!

PS  I think they are just elementary set theory questions, no need to know about $g_i$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, how does that implies $B_i \cap B_{j}= \emptyset$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and more obvious statement is that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i=M$. Each $B_i\subseteq M$ by definition and since there is a finite number of $g_i$ there is for each $x\in M$ $\max\{g_1(x)\cdots g_n(x)\}=f_n(x)$ for the least $i\in \{1,2\cdots n\}$ such that $g_i(x)=\max\{g_1(x)\cdots g_n(x)\}$ we have $x\in B_i$ since $g_i(x)=f_n(x)$ but we also have that since $i$ is the least $g_{i-1}\neq f_n(x)$ so $x\notin B_{i-1}$. For the statement unless we know something else about the $g_i$s or what $M$ is this is false. Here is a very simple counter example $g_1=1, g_2=0, g_3=1$ as constant funcitons. Then $f_3=1$ as well. We have then $B_1=M$ $B_2=\emptyset$ and finally $B_3=M\setminus B_2=M$. These are clearly non disjoint. I do suspect that the author meant to subtract the union of all $B_j$ with $j<i$